# Is there any way to permanently have shell aliases on an imutable system

Tags: shell-script, scripting, terminal

I'm on blendOS https://blendos.co/ which is an immutable operating system which means I cant just add a file to /bin/ like you would do normally to add a custom command
right now I'm keeping it simple and and just trying to add an alias for clear

```
alias c="clear"
```

I'm currently just opening a .sh file with all my custom commands but I would like to get that automatic.

Comment: That sounds like a job for your shell's initialization script in your home directory, e.g. ~/.bashrc . Which is exactly that, the shell script with all the commands you want to run at shell initialization. But it feels strange that you're even mentioning the immutability of the system installation and then describe aliases - pretty unrelated concepts. Is it really just aliases you need?

Comment: Marcus you're exactly right! Thank you! i just and I just want to deal with alias right now yes.

Comment: Uff that blendOS feature list really reads like they're trying to sell me something harder than they care about truth (blend definitely is not the only immutable distro with overlays. They definitely not even invented that, for example). Leave alone what constitutes a good idea(arbitrary mixing of different distro's packaging, release rhythms and packager tools leads to... Interesting conflicts very quickly)

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a job for your shell's initialization script in your home directory, e.g. ~/.bashrc . Which is exactly that, the shell script with all the commands you want to run at shell initialization.